# How do I create a calculator that with one input populates several label fields with different values?

Tags: ios, swift, calculator

I am new to using Xcode, slowly learning as I go. Attempting to create a calculator where I input a weight which will cause multiple different labels to display different values.

[StoryBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruj8j.jpg)

This is how I have the storyboard setup. Basically behind the scenes I need the values calculated for each item. For example, I want to take the user input ("weight in kilograms" x 80) / 24 and have the result show up on the label to the right of "Fluid Rate". At the same time I will need to have a different calculation for each label. 
Here is my code so far.

[ViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvfSa.jpg)

One of the big issues I'm running into so far is that even when I set a value like, **let fluid = 80**, when I try to setup a calculation with it, Xcode tells me I cannot use a textfield with integers or binary operators. How do I go about making Xcode recognize the user input from the textfield as an integer?

Comment: how about e.g. calculate the value (based on your actual formula) then assing it like e.g. `bladeLabe.text = "\(calculatedDoubleValue)"`...?

Comment: Hi holex, I see what you mean but I need the user input in the text field in order to calculate anything. The user input will be an infant's weight in kilograms and thus will be different with every patient.

Comment: sooo... what makes you stop to use your formula(s) with various _input_ values and calculate various _output_ values...? it is supposed to be like `func fluidRate(fromKg kg: Double) -> Double { return kg * 80.0 / 24.0 }`... then you can populate back the value into the label after calculation... don't get me wrong, but I'm not seeing your problem here at all.

Answer (score 1):

I go through the problem you are facing I am giving the sample code snippet which might be helpful to you.

```
var fluidRate = 0
var GIR = 0
var enteredValue = 10 
{
didSet {
        fluidRate =  enteredValue * 10 //consider your formula calculations
        GIR =  enteredValue * 50 //consider your formula calculations

        //you can do like that
        //self.fluidlabel.text = "\(fluidRate)"
    }
}
enteredValue = 30
GIR
fluidRate
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> How do I go about making Xcode recognize the user input from the textfield as an integer?

Read the section *Converting Strings* in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int) for `Int`.

That will get you from text to integer and it looks like you already know how to go the other way

HTH